# Login Issue through Microsoft Authenticator Application

Tags: authenticator

When I am trying to login to the office 365, It is asking Microsoft authenticator code for the verification which was installed in my mobile, But the application itself asking the authenticator code while login to the mobile.
How to resolve the problem...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For the above question,
First you need to go to your Edge browser and click on your profile which was located at the right side in your Edge browser and click on **add sync**.
Then after type **myaccount.microsoft.com** in browser
then it will open your account then select My sign-ins tab---->security info---->add method----->choose a method(phone)----->add country code and mobile number---->Text me--------->Ok
Then it will send OTP to your mobile number and use that OTP to login to your office 365 account....
You can also add another methods to login like authenticator app.....etc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).